# Glide onProgressUpdate listener

Tags: android, android-glide

Is there possible to add onProgressUpdate listener to Glide. I don't mean standart

```
new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I mean listener, that able to publish progress percent during the loading or downloaded bytes size

Comment: dont know about Glide but you can use this library for that purpose https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: @KamranAhmedKhan Good library, but some heavyweight for me. Want to try it with glide previously

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it only with Glide, the API doesn't provide such an option, there is a conversation around this at the [Glide GitHub](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/232)

One of the posts there provided an approach mixing Glide and OkHttp which you can see in https://gist.github.com/TWiStErRob/08d5807e396740e52c90

[Here](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1160)  I have found a more recent approach